# Why is my Javascript canvas image not moving I see no error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to move my Image across the screen.
I am using the html5 canvas element and I am using an Xpos var for the X position of the image. My image is loading fine... but when  try to use the code I am about to show nothing happens it just sits there.... it gives me no error!
Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? if so please let me know. Here's the code,
Thanks

```js
Xpos = Xpos + 5

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush)

function keyPush(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      break;
  }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
var imgPath = "Piskel.png"
var imgObj = new Image()
imgObj.src = imgPath

imgObj.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(imgObj, Xpos, 100, 100, 70)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing just once the canvas, you need a `requestAnimationFrame(callback)` that updates your canvas drawing.

Please take a look to [Canvas tutorial (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial), particularly to [Basic Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations) section